# Pandas invalidindexerror on concat - how to resolve

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am building this table extraction tool using AWS Textract. However, I constantly get the `pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` error. I have tried resetting the index by adding:

```
for dataframe in dataframes:
  dataframe.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Below is my primary code that gives me the error. Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path = 'statements/FNB_statement.pdf'

    # Extract the base name of the file (without extension)
    base_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0]

    # Convert the PDF to a single image
    merged_image = convert_pdf(file_path, f'results/{base_name}_converted.png')

    # Load the image
    image = Image.open(f'results/{base_name}_converted.png')

    # Convert the image to bytes
    image_bytes = save_image_to_bytes(image)

    # Extract tables from the image
    dataframes = extract_tables_from_image_main(image_bytes)

    concatenated_df = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)

    desired_columns = ['Date', 'Description', 'Amount', 'Balance', 'Accrued Bank Charge']

    # Select specific columns based on desired_columns
    filtered_df = concatenated_df[desired_columns]

    # Remove empty rows from the filtered DataFrame
    filtered_df = filtered_df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')

    # Save the filtered DataFrame to a CSV file
    cleaned_csv_filename = f'results/{base_name}_cleaned_data_output.csv'
    filtered_df.to_csv(cleaned_csv_filename, index=False)
    print(f'Cleaned DataFrame saved to {cleaned_csv_filename}')

    # Print the filtered DataFrame
    print(filtered_df)

    # Run the Flask app
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC change:

```
concatenated_df = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
```

Try create default indices:

```
concatenated_df = pd.concat([x.reset_index(drop=True) for x in dataframes], 
                            ignore_index=True)
```

Or create unique columns names, duplicates are removed:

```
concatenated_df = pd.concat([x.loc[:, ~x.columns.duplicated()] for x in dataframes], 
                            ignore_index=True)
```